# WHERE clause Azure CosmosDB Mongo subdocument

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Using Azure CosmosDB Mongo.

I have text fields in documents and subdocuments. Which I want be able to search.

Using `Contains` works fine on the parent document properties. But doesn't seem to look at children at all. And doesn't even return any error.

**Document:**

```
 {
     "TextField1": "this will be found in search",
     "Comments": [{
         "Comment": "amazing post, let's see if this can be foundtoo",
     }, {
         "Comment": "thanks",
     }]
 }
```

**Search:**

```
var postFilter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Where(p => p.TextField1.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText.ToLowerInvariant())) |
                 Builders<MyObject>.Filter.Where(p => p.Comments.Any(pc => pc.Comment.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText.ToLowerInvariant())));

var posts = await Posts.Find(postFilter).ToListAsync();
```

If I use the above code with search "found". It will return the document.

If I use it with search "foundtoo". It will not return anything.

PS: I have tried using `Text` and it is not supported and comes back as an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos Mongo Db may have not implemented whole commands as native MongoDB. I tried the code you mentioned also get the same result as you mentioned.

> Using Contains works fine on the parent document properties. But doesn't seem to look at children at all. And doesn't even return any error.

Please have a try to use the follow code to do that. I test it on my side, it works correctly.

```
var filterResult = collection.Find(Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch("Comments", Builders<Mydata>.Filter.Where(p=>p.Comment.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText.ToLowerInvariant())))).ToList();
```

**The following is my detail steps:**

1.Create a .net project and reference [MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.4.4) more detail please refer to packages.config.

2.Add the Mydata and MyObject class

```
public class MyObject
{
     public string TextField1;
     public Mydata[] Comments;
     [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
     public string Id;
 }

 public class Mydata
 {
     public string Comment;
 }
```

3.Test with following code.

```
  string connectionString = "connection string";
  MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
  settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
  var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
  var searchText = "foundtoo";
  var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("dbname");
  var collection = db.GetCollection<MyObject>("collectionName");
  var mydata1 = new Mydata {Comment = "Thank you"};
  var mydata2 = new Mydata {Comment = "amazing post, let's see if this can be foundtoo"};
  var list = new List<Mydata> {mydata1, mydata2};
  Mydata[] mydatas = {mydata1,mydata2};
  collection.InsertOneAsync(new MyObject
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                TextField1 = "this will be found in search",
                Comments = mydatas

            }).Wait();
   var filterResult = collection.Find(Builders<MyObject>.Filter.ElemMatch("Comments", Builders<Mydata>.Filter.Where(p=>p.Comment.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(searchText.ToLowerInvariant())))).ToList();
```

[image]

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.4.4" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. Will give it a try.

Comment: you are a star!